# How to store an int value from stored procedure and pass it to controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have table license as below

```
table Licence
 [ LID(pk) int,
   ProID(FK) int,
   SK string,
   QTY int,
   LIS int,
   LIU int
]
```

and I have "chklin" as stored procedure to retrieve LIU.

```
procedure [dbo].[chklin]
(@LID int)
as
begin
select LIU from license where LID=@LID
end
```

Now in my License controller, I have below action

```
public ActionResult Chk(int L)
    {
        SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
        dbContext.chklin(L) // this should check the LIU value, how to pass it 
    to below IF statement

if (A == 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "No more license available";
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("create", "users");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome, could you clear up what exactly you are asking? Thanks

Comment: you can use function to check

Comment: dbContext.chklin(L) // this return an int value, how to pass it to if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of the result of the result of the procedure to a variable and check the value of the Variable in your `If` statement. Like this

```
var A = dbContext.chklin(L)
if(A == 0){
 ViewBag.Message = "No more license available";
} else{
 return RedirectToAction("create", "users");
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, first it shows that you can't use == as this is for boolean and when you make it one "=" it will also show error on number 0 saying "cannot implicitly convert int to system.data.entity.core.objectresult<int?>"

Comment: Im not sure but maybe as @Ersin Gülbahar commented , that i should use function instead of store procedure

Comment: If the result of your Stored procedure is int, it should definitely work. Can you check what the stored procedure is returning? Also, can you not use linq instead of stored procedure?

Comment: dbContext.chklin(L) return an int , but var A is showing null.